# nested accordions do not expand properly in ui bootstrap

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

When an accordion is nested inside another, the child accordion does not expand the height of its parent.
Please can anybody tell me that how I can fix it?

I have the following code:

```
    <uib-accordion>
<uib-accordion-group is-open="status.open"> 
        <uib-accordion-heading> 
            Parent Accordion <i class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': status.open, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !status.open}"></i>
       </uib-accordion-heading>
        <uib-accordion> 
            <uib-accordion-group is-open="nest1.open"> 
                <uib-accordion-heading> 
                    Nested Accordion 1 <i class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': nest1.open, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !nest1.open}"></i>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
            </uib-accordion-group>
            <uib-accordion-group is-open="nest2.open"> 
                <uib-accordion-heading> 
                    Nested Accordion 2 <i class="pull-left glyphicon" ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-minus': nest2.open, 'glyphicon glyphicon-plus': !nest2.open}"></i>
                </uib-accordion-heading>
            </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
    </uib-accordion-group>
</uib-accordion>
```

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

This issue was fixed in 0.14.3.

https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4561